# Install ESXi 4.1 on Windows Server 2008 Hyper-v

Tags: windows-server-2008, vmware-esxi, hyper-v

Can I install ESXi on WIndows Server 2008 with Hyper-V? It stucks as in the printscreen:

[image]

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: why not? I have one PC and since i have Server 2008 installed i thought that it's better to install in Hyper-V than over vmware player/workstation

Comment: Are you trying to run hypervisor as vm?This would defeat whole point of virtualization.

Comment: I've never tried it but you can run esxi inside esxi - in case you were interested.

Comment: Why not install ESXi on bare metal and Server 2008 as a guest.  That's a more traditional method and likely to get you better results and support.

Comment: i'm just testing....

Comment: Why test a configuration that no-one in their right mind would ever do anything productive with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, neither ESXi or Hyper-V will run as a guest of the other (versions available as of writing this).